# How to delete duplicates using MongoDB Aggregations in MongoDB Compass Community

Tags: mongodb, duplicates, aggregation-framework

I somehow created duplicates of every single entry in my database. Currently, there are 176039 documents and counting, half are duplicates. Each document is structured like so

```
_id : 5b41d9ccf10fcf0014fe8917
originName : "Hartsfield Jackson Atlanta International Airport"
destinationName : "Antigua"
totalDuration : 337
```

Inside the MongoDB Compass Community App for Mac under the Aggregations tab, I was able to find duplicates using this pipeline

```
[
    {$group: {
        _id: {originName: "$originName", destinationName: "$destinationName"},
        count: {$sum: 1}}},
    {$match: {count: {"$gt": 1}}}
]
```

I'm not sure how to move forward and delete the duplicates at this point. I'm assuming it has something to do with `$out`.

Edit: Something I didn't notice until now is that the values for totalDuration on each double are actually different.

Comment: add `{$project:{_id:0, "originName":"$_id.originName", "destinationName":"$_id.destinationName"}},{ $out : collectionname }`. This will replace the documents in your current collection with documents from aggregation pipeline. If you need totalDuration in the collection then add that field in both group and project stage before running the pipeline.

Comment: This worked exactly as expected. Can you turn this into an answer so I can upvote it? Also, I made an edit to the question. The totalDuration values are actually different for some reason. If I totalDuration to $group then $match will not find anything.

Comment: Do you want to keep the totalDuration in your output ? If yes do you want both ?

Comment: Yes, but only one and the first one although it doesn’t matter which.

Comment: Add `totalDuration:{$first:"$totalDuration"}` in the group stage and include in the $project stage as `totalDuration:1`

Comment: Ah, easy enough. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
{$project:{_id:0, "originName":"$_id.originName", "destinationName":"$_id.destinationName"}},
{ $out : collectionname }
```

This will replace the documents in your current collection with documents from aggregation pipeline. If you need totalDuration in the collection then add that field in both group and project stage before running the pipeline